# Unable to bind any program to IPv4 TCP port 80 on Mac

Tags: macos, tcp, port, ipv4

I started debugging an issue with docker containers, confirmed it also happened on a plain nodejs + express on my Mac, and even netcat. Basically, I can bind to IPv4 TCP port 81 but not 80. It seems nothing else is already listening on that port, and the firewall is disabled.

To reproduce this, on a fresh boot I run the following to check that nothing is listening on port 80:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:80
$ sudo netstat -an | grep 80.*LISTEN
```

Both commands show nothing.

Then, on one terminal I run netcat to echo everything received in port 80: `sudo nc -l -p 80`.

Now:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:80
netcat    1700   root    3u  IPv4 0xcd04564dc212a9f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

$ sudo netstat -an | grep 80.*LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

But on a separate terminal I try to connect and get connection refused:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying 192.168.10.16...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.10.16: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

This actually works fine with port 81, I can connect using IP 127.0.0.1 and everything I type on one terminal appears on the other:

```
Terminal 1:
$ sudo nc -l -p 81
asdf

Terminal 2:
$ telnet localhost 81
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
asdf
```

Additionally:

- `docker run -p 0.0.0.0:80:80 httpd:2.4` binds successfully to IPv6 ::1:80, but not IPv4 addresses. `curl http://[::1]` returns the homepage, but `curl http://127.0.0.1` shows connection refused.
- Trying to bind to a specific IP address with `docker run -p 192.168.10.16:80:80 httpd:2.4`, froze for exactly 2 minutes (!) and ended up showing in `sudo lsof` as LISTEN, but I still get connection refused.
- A simple nodejs + express server shows a similar behavior.
- Same happens with ports 443 (doesn't work) and 444 (works as expected).
- Since I'm not running any SSH server, I tested this on port 22 and it works just fine too. So far, the only 2 ports having problems that I know of are 80 and 443.
- I used to run the builtin Apache server on this Mac a long time ago, and also through `homebrew`, in both cases using ports 80 and 443. I don't think this would be an issue because port 80 and 443 are actually free when I boot, but I mention this just in case this means something to somebody.

It smells like something is blocking the ports rather than using them, but I checked the firewall in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall and it's disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I `sudo pfctl -F all`, I remove all packet filter rules, then it works as expected. I still need to find how to remove the rule blocking/redirecting ports 80/443 yet, but until I do I'm leaving this comment here in case it helps somebody.

Comment: I found the solution, posted the answer but it got deleted. I spent 2 days trying to fix this, I've seen countless questions about similar problems without answers, and for some reason it gets deleted. For those interested, the problem was I had `pfctl` running. I just wanted to bind to port 80, but since `pfctl` automatically redirected everything in port 80 to 8080, I just bound to 8080 and I got the functionality I wanted. Another possibility would be to disable `pfctl` altogether, or yet another possibility is to tweak its rules so it doesn't redirect port 80 to 8080 (also, 443 to 8443).